# Get-ChildItem: any option of getting the real file size when using ADS?

Tags: powershell, ntfs

Anyone knows if there's a way to get the correct file size when listing NTFS files which have several streams?

It looks  like I'm only able to get the size for the default data stream, but I'm hoping there's something like the `dir /r` option that we had in CMD.EXE.

Comment: yes, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380498/powershell-list-all-alternate-data-stream-information-from-one-directory

Comment: Try: `Get-ChildItem | Measure-Object -Sum Length | Select-Object Count, Sum`.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -File -Force |Get-Item -Stream * -Force |Select-Object Length, @{N='FileName'; E={$_.PSChildName -replace '::\$DATA$',''}}`